# titan1.0.0 can't connect to hadoop1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, titan, gremlin

Right now I am using Titan1.0.0-hadoop1 and hadoop1.2.1, and I have set Class_path in /etc/profile like this:

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/conf
export HADOOP_CONF=$HADOOP_PREFIX/conf
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/conf
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin
```

However, in gremlin, when I type hdfs, I get this:

```
gremlin> hdfs
==>org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem@48bfb884
```

But when I use titan-0.5.4-hadoop1, I get a right connection I think:

```
gremlin> hdfs
==>DFS[DFSClient[clientName=DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1221412592_1, ugi=luheng]]
```

Anybody knows why?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the HDFS running on the same nodes as Titan or on different nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` on the `CLASSPATH` before starting `gremlin.sh`.

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_PREFIX/conf
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR
./bin/gremlin.sh
```

Also note that `YARN_HOME` and `YARN_CONF_DIR` would only be for Hadoop 2.x.

Comment: Thank you very much Jason! It works! So exciting and so happy right now.

Answer (score 0):

Is all nodes are working? If not, then instead of `HADOOP_PREFIX` use `HADOOP_HOME` and path should be like this

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think all nodes are working, because when I type jps, I got this: 
    3283 SecondaryNameNode
    3108 DataNode
    2937 NameNode  
    3388 JobTracker  
    3549 TaskTracker
    5326 Jps
    5055 Console